# QueryContinueDrag never fires

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I want my WPF application to indicate that a drag and drop operation should be cancelled in certain situations. The operation is being started from an external application (e.g. Windows Explorer).

I've tried hooking up the following events to see when they fire;

```
<someControl 
    AllowDrop="True" 
    DragOver="OnDragOver" 
    PreviewQueryContinueDrag="OnPreviewQueryContinueDrag"
    QueryContinueDrag="OnQueryContinueDrag" />
```

The idea being that I would let the other application know that it should end the operation by specifying `DragAction.Cancel` on the event args.

However, neither `PreviewQueryContinueDrag` nor `QueryContinueDrag` ever fire. I hooked up `DragOver` just to make sure anything was firing at all, and it works as expected.

Am I missing something, or is it the case that the drag source application just doesn't do anything with this event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.querycontinuedrag.aspx), the `QueryContinueDrag` event is for the drag source, not for the drop target. In your case, the drag source is the external application, the drop target is the WPF control. Therefore, you can use this event only for drag&drop operations initiated by a WPF application.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - thanks. I'll need to work out some other way of handling my scenario then.